# How to store the tagged values (like gmail to field) as a string in a variable using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autosuggest, magicsuggest

Anyone please tell me a solution to solve this problem.
am using magicSuggest plugin to achieve a search box like autosuggestion drop down field.
and i got it working with database entries. but now am not able to get the value that selected by the user and displayed as a tag or like a token in a text box field.
i want to get the value as a string not as a tag or token like http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/

i need a solution like exactly stack overflow's tags field above the post your question button in the post question page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you not use getSelectedItems()?

Comment: i tried but not working:-(

Comment: Are you using magic suggest or just trying to get the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- getValue() will return an array of values as specified by the valueField property (default to id)
- getSelection() will return an array of records with all of their properties.

So dependeing upon your JSON records, you could easily get the values using one of those methods.

Comment: Thank You,but its not clear to me... please explain in detail.

Comment: Can you post your current code? Did you look at the documentation examples for those 2 methods? On the documentation (http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html) you can click on the public method names in red to see examples.